# IS NULL in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, isnull

I am learning the PostgreSQL and I need to know if the below condition will work. As per my understanding it won't.

But my friend told me that, it will be logical way to accept it in Postgres.

Please confirm.

```
select a.ename,
       a.dept_id
from
table a
inner join table b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id is null;  -- this condition is wrong as my understanding.
```

Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: The syntax itself is correct (i.e. the query will run without an error assuming you use table and column names that actually exist) But unless you tell us what you want to achieve with that condition, it's impossible to tell whether it's wrong or correct.

Comment: This query will always return an empty resultset. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `ID IS NULL` is the **only way** you can check whether a field contains a NULL or not. `NULL` in SQL means `Unkown` and the result of any comparison with an unknown value is itself `Unknown`. When you force SQL to use `UNKNOWN` in a boolean expression, it treats it as false. This means that `ID=NULL` will always be false, and so would `ID!=NULL`

Comment: BTW in that query `WHERE a.ID IS NULL` will discard all rows. The `INNER JOIN` will only return values that *don't* have NULLs in the join fields. `NULL=NULL` is also false which means `inner join table b
on a.id = b.id` will never return NULL IDs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `NULL = NULL` is not `FALSE`, but in essence you are right. The query is guaranteed to return an empty result.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. My apologies for not giving what exactly i was looking for.   Though the syntax is correct, my argument with my friend is this query not going to return any records. I can prove him with all your comments here.  The purpose of the query is to combine both tables with matching records. So the WHERE clause will not be valid in my query.  Thank you all once again.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, but if you're not selecting nothing of the table b you dont have to make that inner joins, it's just a suggestion, and on this case, the condition of the inner join is not logical, because the query will return nothing.
You want to get the rows where an 'id' is null and is equals to the id of the other table, the query could be correct if the WHERE condition check anothe column or the columns on the INNER JOIN are others

```
SELECT a.ename, a.dept_id , b.something
FROM table_1 a inner join table_2 b 
ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE a.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I do have to SELECT other fields from the table B. But my question here is when we do inner join with a.id=b.id, how is this possible to get the records if we use WHERE a.id is NULL. Definitely it's not going to return any records right.?